# What is an equivalent phrase to the colloquial "I know, right!?"

Tags: set-phrases

What are the Japanese equivalent phrases for the phrase "I know, right?!"

The scenario is my friend said 「PS4には最高だね」, and I'd like to respond with something akin to "I know, right?!" 「でしょ！？」 comes to mind but I'm unsure if it has the same effect.

Comment: "I know right!?"!? What does that mean in English? "でしょ" seems to be what you're looking for, but you have at least one typo in your friend's statement and I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, so it would help the answerer if you clarified your question.

Comment: I agree with [this answer on ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2473/28567), which says that *"I know, right?"* suggests "empathy in addition to agreement".  I'd add that it's both friendly and informal.  (It's treated like a single word, sometimes slangily abbreviated to "Inorite?!" or similar.)

Comment: Has an alc entry btw, http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=i+know+right&ref=sa

Comment: @Earthling Typo? You mean だぬ? It's Internet slang...

Comment: Also things like: そうよね！ or そうだよな！^^;

Comment: @Chocolate,@snailplane Oh dear, it seems that this question is way above my head ;) (regarding both English & Japanese)... I'll be quiet.

Comment: @Earthling くじけちゃダメだぬ。それに「だぬ」は流行りのネット用語なので覚えなくていいだぬ。

Comment: あ、「だぬ」が「だね」になってる・・・(@_@。 くじけそうだぬ。

Comment: @Chocolate 「だぬ」とは何なのか、教えていただけませんかな。ググってもよくわからないんです。

Comment: @ZhenLin 語源は分からないですが、[ここ](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1376786958)や[ここ](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1136760821) では2chからとか若者言葉とか言ってます。ウザい語尾と見なされる場合もあるようです（[ここ](http://kotonoha.cc/no/173933)）。もう、ちょっと古いようだぬ。「だお」の方が広く使われていたようだお。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `でしょ（う・っ）！` is what many young people use (optionally prefixed with `そう`; but often without).  I'm not sure if this usage is just among the younger generations (under 30), or extends to all ages, but I haven't often heard middle-aged or elderly people use it in the same vernacular (much like I don't often hear middle-aged/elderly people say "I know right (Inorite)?!" in English).

Additionally, "Inorite?!" seems to be more prevalent among young women and girls in English.  ***My*** experience in Japan with `でしょ！` was similar, but that's not to say it's mainly used by お嬢さん everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other suggestions for expressing (enthusiastic) agreement:

- そうですとも!
- まったくだ（よ）！
- マジでそうよ
- そのとおり!
- 当然だ
- 確かにそうだ